# Unable to open localhost?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lampp

I have been using Lampp on a test machine. OS is Ubuntu 12.1. It was working fine before and running my scripts. Then it began displaying a pop-up asking me if I would like to open or save the file? I have tried changing the ports and restarted the machine and restart Lampp. Nothing has worked so far though.

Comment: did you read the apache error log?

Comment: Have you opened the file? What's in it?

Answer (score 1):

Your MIME types are wrong and/or mod_php isn't loaded.

What is in the files?  If they contain your PHP code,  Apache is serving the files out rather than putting them through PHP. Check you are loading mod_php.

If they contain the output of the PHP code (i.e. the HTML) then they aren't being given the correct MIME types.  I'm not sure where this is done, I think Apache or PHP adds the headers automatically.  Check the Apache MIME types config

Comment: Thanks, I checked the logs and can't see anything that strikes me as the issue. Although it is more than likely in there. I checked the mime.types file and it is not PHP. How do I check if I am loading mod_php?